# How to set color of highest number in datagrid view to a BackColor

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
        int highest = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < dgvCalories.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
        {
           for (int col = 0; col < dgvCalories.ColumnCount; col++)
           {
            if (calories[row, col] > highest)
                highest = calories[row, col];

           }

     }
```

I want to know what code is needed in order for me to highlight this highest value with a color in a datagrid view

Comment: What do you mean _doesn't work_? You got an exception or what?

Comment: No exception, The cell just does not get highlighted with the color

Comment: Determining the lowest is not a problem as that works. I just have no idea how to change the color once i have determined it. I am doing second year Software Dev. So please bear that in mind. Also my program works as follows. I read values (calories) into a datagrid. I then save these values to a .txt file. I then click the restore data button then the code is displayed in a new datagrid, in this case called dataGridView1.

Comment: fair enough i have not actually tested the lowest but i have the highest and it is similar

Comment: int highest = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < dgvCalories.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
            {
               for (int col = 0; col < dgvCalories.ColumnCount; col++)
               {
                if (calories[row, col] > highest)
                    highest = calories[row, col];
           
               }
                
            }
            MessageBox.Show("" + highest);

Comment: no it does not work. My code is a trail and error code, the code provided was just one of many ways in which i actually tried in order for it to work. thats why it is so disjointed and probably really wrong

Comment: FYI -- `SelectionBackColor` only matters when the cell is _selected_.  You probably want `BackColor`.

Comment: ya i have changed that already.

Comment: This is how i determined my highest.

Comment: So if you're having problems setting the BackColor of the highest value cell, why did you remove that code from the question, especially after you stated that _ya i have changed that already_?

Comment: I changed it within the lowest code. You are actually not offering any sort of help to me.. i have stated what i need help with. and that is how to change the color, the rest of the details are actually irrelevant!

Comment: Now based on the given code, what have you tried?  The original code would never _attempt_ to set the back color because the "find lowest" algorithm was buggy.  With a correct algorithm, you setting the `SelectionBackColor` (not what you wanted) of every cell that was the lowest _so far_ as you traversed the data.  Had you stepped through the code with a debugger, you could gain the knowledge that every line you expected to get hit was, in fact, hit and could then ask a more directed question.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is backwards

```
if (calories[row, col] > lowest)
```

You need

```
if (calories[row, col] < lowest)
```

Second, you probably will need to loop through once to identify the lowest number, then again to set the color. Currently, you'll set the color on each location if it is the lowest SO FAR, no lowest overall.

Comment: fyi -- the question has changed a couple times since you posted this answer.